# Shortest route modification

Tags: c++, function, dijkstra

Is there a way to modify this to show the route of the shortest path? For example, if i had a list of numbers like (3,1),(3,0),(4,3),(2,1) the output for getting from 4 to 1 would be 4->3,3->1

```
// Prints shortest paths from src to all other vertices
void Graph::shortestPath(int src)
{
    // Create a priority queue to store vertices that
    // are being preprocessed. This is weird syntax in C++.
    // Refer below link for details of this syntax
    // http://geeksquiz.com/implement-min-heap-using-stl/
    priority_queue< iPair, vector <iPair> , greater<iPair> > pq;


    // Create a vector for distances and initialize all
    // distances as infinite (INF)
    vector<int> dist(V, INF);

    // Insert source itself in priority queue and initialize
    // its distance as 0.
    pq.push(make_pair(0, src));
    dist[src] = 0;

    /* Looping till priority queue becomes empty (or all
      distances are not finalized) */
    while (!pq.empty())
    {
        // The first vertex in pair is the minimum distance
        // vertex, extract it from priority queue.
        // vertex label is stored in second of pair (it
        // has to be done this way to keep the vertices
        // sorted distance (distance must be first item
        // in pair)
        int u = pq.top().second;
        pq.pop();

        // 'i' is used to get all adjacent vertices of a vertex
        list< pair<int, int> >::iterator i;
        for (i = adj[u].begin(); i != adj[u].end(); ++i)
        {
            // Get vertex label and weight of current adjacent
            // of u.
            int v = (*i).first;
            int weight = (*i).second;

            //  If there is shorted path to v through u.
            if (dist[v] > dist[u] + weight)
            {
                // Updating distance of v
                dist[v] = dist[u] + weight;
                pq.push(make_pair(dist[v], v));
            }
        }
    }

    // Print shortest distances stored in dist[]
    printf("Vertex   Distance from Source\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < V; ++i)
            printf("%d \t\t %d\n", i, dist[i]);
    }
```

Putting in an array that stores the numbers of the path like 4,3,3,1 (using above example) seems like the best idea but i don't know where to insert the array in this code to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as you save the distances for each vertex in the `dist` vector, save the predecessor vertex that last updated it in a vector called `predecessor`.

```
vector<int> dist(V, INF);
vector<int> predecessor(V, 0);
```

Then whenever you update the distance, update the predecessor:

```
dist[v] = dist[u] + weight;
predecessor[v] = u;
```

Finally, you can trace for any vertex the shortest path (Backward) to the source:

```
printf("Vertex   Distance from Source      shortest path from source\n");
for (int i = 0; i < V; ++i)
{
        printf("%d \t\t %d\t\t", i, dist[i]);
        int j = i;
        do
        {
             printf("%d,", j);
             j = predecessor[j];
        } while(j != src);
        printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a homework problem.

Your idea to store the numbers of the path would be great, if this were a DFS. Unfortunately, Djikstra's algorithm doesn't naturally keep track of the path like a DFS does; it simply takes the next closest node and updates the distance values. It's probably more similar to a BFS in that regard.

What you could do is as you update the distances to each node, somehow store which node you're coming from (maybe in your `iPair` struct if you're allowed to, maybe in a map/array if you have a way to ID your nodes). I'll call it a "from" reference for the sake of this post. Then, each time you find a shorter path to a node, you can also update that from reference.

How do you find the path to a given node then? Simple: just start at the end node, and follow the "from" references back to the source.